# Setting a nullable UShort using kotlin-reflect

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-reflect

Why can't I set a UShort using reflection in kotlin?  I extracted my problem into a unit test.

My test looks like this:

```kotlin
class Junk {
    var DA: UShort? = null
}

class Tests {
    @Test
    fun testSetShort() {
        var uut = Junk()
        val value = 100
        val expect = 100

        val properties: Collection<KProperty<*>> = Junk::class.memberProperties
        val property = properties.find { property -> property.name == "DA" }
        if (property is KMutableProperty<*>) {
            property.setter.call(uut, value.toUShort())  /* FAILS HERE */
        }

        assertEquals(expect, uut.DA)
        System.err.println("ok")
    }
}
```

The result is

```
argument type mismatch
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.calls.CallerImpl$Method.callMethod(CallerImpl.kt:97)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.calls.CallerImpl$Method$Instance.call(CallerImpl.kt:113)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.calls.InlineClassAwareCaller.call(InlineClassAwareCaller.kt:142)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KCallableImpl.call(KCallableImpl.kt:108)
    at Tests.testSetShort(testSetUshort.kt:24)
```

Things I have tried:

- Force *value* to be of type UShort? in case the nullability was the problem (though that's not a problem when I try to do the same thing to a nullable String var)

Comment: I wonder if there's a bug in reflection vs. inline classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's a problem with inline classes. as you know inline classed are still experimental and `UShort` is an inline class which acts as a wrapper around `Short`:

```
public inline class UShort @PublishedApi internal constructor(@PublishedApi internal val data: Short) : Comparable<UShort>
```

let's take a look at the bytecode for your code. this is the summarized bytecode of your `DA` property:

```
private Lkotlin/UShort; DA
  @Lorg/jetbrains/annotations/Nullable;() // invisible

  // access flags 0x11
  public final getDA-XRpZGF0()Lkotlin/UShort;
  @Lorg/jetbrains/annotations/Nullable;() // invisible
  
    ...

  public final setDA-ffyZV3s(Lkotlin/UShort;)V
    // annotable parameter count: 1 (visible)
    // annotable parameter count: 1 (invisible)
    @Lorg/jetbrains/annotations/Nullable;() // invisible, parameter 0

    ...
```

as you know inline classes should be ignored and deleted after compilation but because you defined `DA` as nullable, the compiled type is still `UShort` instead of `Short`.

however, when you call `Int.toUShort` on an object, the compiled code has no sign of `UShort` and it converts to `Short` instead(as it should because it's an inline class). that's why you get an `argument type mismatch` error. because the setter needs a `UShort` but you are giving it a `Short`.
that explains why your code runs successfully with `Short` instead of `UShort`.

anyways, if you really need to use `UShort` in your code, you should not make it nullable, use a `lateinit var` instead and it works fine. because if it's not nullable, the `DA` property's type would be `Short` after compilation

```
var DA: UShort = 0u

//bytecode:

 private S DA   // S is JVM type for Short

  // access flags 0x11
  public final getDA-Mh2AYeg()S
   ...

  // access flags 0x11
  public final setDA-xj2QHRw(S)V
   ...
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining!  I think it will be easiest for me to not use a UShort.  I was just excited to find those, because certain things in java - like the fact that a byte is signed - have always driven me a little nuts, so when I saw these UShort and others I got a little too careless.  I'll figure out a workaround ... maybe just make it an Int, since 0-65535 fits just fine in an int.

Comment: you're welcome. as you know inline class is just a fancy wrapper. it does not remove the sign bit which you have a problem with :D